# Modify Choice Validation in Choice Prompt - Bot Framework Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

Currently having a choice_prompt that asks the user for some options to validate. To move to the next step of the waterfall, the user's input has to either be the value, or a synonym associated with that value.

If a user types something that is not the value or synonym, the choicePrompt just loops. I want to warn the user "Enter a number between 1 - 6".

```html
async question2_1(step) {
    return await step.prompt(CHOICE_PROMPT, {
        prompt: '"1/3: How easy were the course materials to navigate and follow?',
        choices: ChoiceFactory.toChoices([' = Very Hard', '', '', '', '', ' = Very Easy']),
        style: ListStyle.list
    });
}
```

Comment: Use the retry prompt option

Comment: Did you try a custom prompt validator?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a retryPrompt option like this:

```js
async question2_1(step) {
    return await step.prompt(CHOICE_PROMPT, {
        prompt: '"1/3: How easy were the course materials to navigate and follow?',
        choices: ChoiceFactory.toChoices([' = Very Hard', '', '', '', '', ' = Very Easy']),
        style: ListStyle.list,
        retryPrompt: 'Enter a number between 1 - 6'
    });
}
```

If you want any of the original prompt to be re-prompted, you'll need to add that too. The user will only get re-prompted with the text you add under retryPrompt.

EDIT: I was looking at this again to use synonyms and I think despite displaying as a numbered list, you aren't going to get the expected values with all those null strings. Maybe I'm wrong because I haven't done a choice like that, but I would probably explicitly define my choices like below. This allows you to set a separate Title (shown) and Value (send on backend) for each choice, as well as add synonyms if you want (you can also add synonyms with the simpler definition as you have above).

```js
async question2_1(step) {
    return await step.prompt(CHOICE_PROMPT, {
        prompt: '"1/3: How easy were the course materials to navigate and follow?',
        choices: [
            {value:'1', action: {type: 'imBack', title: '= Very Hard', value: '1'}, synonyms: ['1']},
            {value: '2', action: {type: 'imBack', title: ' ', value: '2'}, synonyms: ['2']},
            {value: '3', action: {type: 'imBack', title: ' ', value: '3'}, synonyms: ['3']},
            {value: '4', action: {type: 'imBack', title: ' ', value: '4'}, synonyms: ['4']},
            {value: '5', action: {type: 'imBack', title: ' ', value: '5'}, synonyms: ['5']},
            {value: '6', action: {type: 'imBack', title: '= Very Easy', value: '6'}, synonyms: ['6']},
        ],
        style: ListStyle.list,
        retryPrompt: 'Enter a number between 1 - 6'
    });
}
```

Comment: The op said "or a synonym associated with that value", hence he needs a custom validator I guess.

Comment: I believe his issue was with the reprompt message, not with the choice validation. However, I will add the syntax for the synonyms to the choice syntax for clarity.